# Tomcat Session Replication

Tags: session, tomcat, replication, shared

I am trying to develope an application with tomcat running in several computers of same LAN trying representing several nodes and each of them runs an application with a single shared session(Ex. shared document editor such as google docs.). in my understanding so far I need a single shared session and several users need to update the doc symultaneously and each others updates are reflected on each others we interfaces almost imidietly. Can I acheve this with with tomcat's clustering feature. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Configuration_Example or is this just a faluir recovery system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat's clustering feature is meant for failover - if one node fails, user can carry on working while being transparently sent to another node without a need to log in again.

What you are trying to achieve is a totally different scenario and I think using session for this is just wrong. If you go back to Google Doc example, how would you achieve granting (revoking?) document access to another user? What do you do when session times out - create the document again? Also, how would you define which users would be able to access selected documents?

You would need to persist this data somewhere (DB?) anyway so implement or reuse some existing ACL system where you could share information about users and document permissions.